# takeWhile implementation in JavaScript - Looking for better ideas

Tags: javascript, haskell, recursion

Haskell has a `takeWhile` function:

```
Prelude> takeWhile odd [1,3,5,7,8,9]
[1,3,5,7]
```

It “takes” elements from a list as long as applying the predicate function results in `True`. At the point it becomes `False`, it stops.

How can we implement it?

Here is a Haskell recursive approach I came up with:

```
takewhile::(a->Bool)->[a]->[a]
takewhile _ [] = []
takewhile f (x:xs) | f x == True = x : takewhile f xs
                   | otherwise = []
```

It keeps on calling itself as long as predicate `f x` is `True`, otherwise it returns an empty list without calling itself.

I could come up with the following implementation for JavaScript. It is a bit verbose and invokes defining another function to pass the intermediate result around:

```
function takeWhile(f, xs) {
 return take(f, xs, [])
}

function take(f, xs, arr) {
 if(!xs || xs.length === 0) {
 return arr
 }
 x = xs.shift()
 if(f(x)) {
   arr.push(x)
   return take(f, xs, arr)
 } else {
   return arr
 }
}

takeWhile((x)=>{
 return x % 2 !== 0
},[1,3,5,7,9,11])
```

Are there better ideas for implementing it in JavaScript?

Comment: This looks like it should be made runnable and posted on Code Review.

Comment: It doesn't look like you care about laziness here so I don't see the need for generators: https://repl.it/repls/StiffImaginaryThings

Comment: @naomik: The code is elegant, can you please add it as an answer?

Comment: @naomik: keen to know, would you recommend any book for functional programming in JS?

Comment: @naomik: of course, that `Empty` thing was what I was looking for... Nice idea!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want your `takeWhile` to perform like in HS, i.e. lazily, you need generators in JS:

```js
function* takeWhile(fn, xs) {
    for (let x of xs)
        if (fn(x))
            yield x;
        else
            break;
}

function* naturalNumbers() {
    let n = 0;
    while (true)
        yield n++;
}

result = takeWhile(x => x < 10, naturalNumbers())
console.log([...result])
```

A straight port of the HS code is also possible, but it only works with materialized arrays (that is, eagerly):

```js
// would be nice, but JS sucks ;(
// let takeWhile = (f, [x, ...xs]) => f(x) ? [x, ...takeWhile(f, xs)] : [];

let takeWhile = (f, xs) => xs.length ? takeWhileNotEmpty(f, xs) : [];
let takeWhileNotEmpty = (f, [x, ...xs]) =>  f(x) ? [x, ...takeWhile(f, xs)] : [];


let odd = x => x % 2
a = [1,3,5,7,8,9]
r = takeWhile(odd, a)
console.log(r)
```

Actually, as @naomik shows [here](https://repl.it/repls/StiffImaginaryThings) there's a better way to deal with empty lists:

```js
let nil = {};
let takeWhile = (f, [x = nil, ...xs]) => (x === nil || !f(x)) 
    ? [] : [x, ...takeWhile(f, xs)];

console.log(takeWhile(x => x % 2, [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9]));
```

Finally, your initial attempt does have a point, because, unlike the above, it's tail-recursive, which is a Good Thing. It can be written more concisely as

```
let takeWhile = (f, xs) => take1(f, xs, []);
let take1 = (f, xs, acc) => xs.length ? take2(f, xs, acc) : acc;
let take2 = (f, [x, ...xs], acc) => f(x) ? take1(f, xs, acc.concat(x)) : acc;
```

A combination of both approaches (that is, a recursive generator) left as an exercise...

Answer (score 4):

Here's a concise solution:

```
const takeWhile = (fn, arr) => {
  const [x, ...xs] = arr;

  if (arr.length > 0 && fn(x)) {
    return [x, ...takeWhile(fn, xs)]
  } else {
    return [];
  }
};
```

---

Here's an extra condensed version of the above:

```
const takeWhile = 
  (fn, a) => a.length && fn(a[0]) ? [a[0], ...takeWhile(fn, a.slice(1))] : [];
```

It's not easily readable, so I don't recommend you use the condensed version.

---

A tail recursive version:

```
const takeWhile = (fn, arr) => {
  const recur = (a, acc) => {
    const [x, ...xs] = a;

    if (a.length > 0 && fn(x)) {
      return recur(xs, [...acc, x]);
    } else {
      return acc;
    }
  }

  return recur(arr, []);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
    function takeWhile(array, predicate) {
      const index = array.findIndex((el, i) => !predicate(el, i));
            
      return index >= 0
        ? array.slice(0, index)
        : array;
    }
        
    console.log(takeWhile([1, 2, 3, 4, -1, 5, 6, 7], item => item > 0));
```

Comment: This is nice.  It's simple and straightforward.  If you only need to work with arrays, this is a great solution.  But note that the accepted solution is strictly more powerful, as it works with any iterable.  And each version of it is also simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop with fliag, [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/fuxacixise/edit?js,console)

```
const takeWhile = (func, arr) => {
  for(let i = 0, isCorrect; !isCorrect; i++){
    if(!func(arr[i]) || i >= arr.length){isCorrect = true;}
    else {
     console.log(arr[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

This function takes two arguments. One will be your predicate, second array.
So loop will end if your predicate fails or array ends. It will not return any value, but if you need just add return statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine slice and findIndex functions to replicate takeWhile behavior.

```js
let arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90];
//the predicate to findIndex needs to be inverted

//equivalent to arr.takeWhile(i => i !== 55);
let filtered1 = arr.slice(0, arr.findIndex(i => i === 55) == -1 ? arr.length : arr.findIndex(i => i === 55));
console.log(filtered1);
//prints [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]

//equivalent to arr.takeWhile(i => i !== 10);
let filtered2 = arr.slice(0, arr.findIndex(i => i === 10) == -1 ? arr.length : arr.findIndex(i => i === 10));
console.log(filtered2);
//prints []

//equivalent to arr.takeWhile(i => i < 90);
//using iife in case calling findIndex twice is of concern
let filtered3 = arr.slice(0, (function(){
  let idx = arr.findIndex(i => i >= 90);
  idx = idx == -1 ? arr.length : idx;
  return idx;
})());
console.log(filtered3);
//prints [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
```

Comment: This does not work when the condition does not match