# Remove from array until criterion is met

Tags: typescript

I have an array with objects inside like this:

```
{ role: 'someRole', content: 'someContent' }
```

Now I want to remove elements from my array starting from the last added item. I want to remove them until the sum of all characters in all content attributes that are still in the array are below some threshold.

In Dart I am doing this:

```dart
const int maxCharacters = 4000;
int sum = 0;
return chatEntries
    .reversed
    .takeWhile((TextChatEntry chatEntry) {
      sum += chatEntry.content.length;
      return sum <= maxCharacters;
    })
    .toList()
    .reversed
    .toList();
```

In TypeScript there is no `takeWhile` which is why I am not sure what the best approach is to do this. Should I just iterate over it in a for-loop or are there any other handy built-in functions?

Comment: I don't know dart at all, but looking at the docs, it seems takeWhile is the equivalent of Array.filter().  You should also be looking for JS docs not TS docs for core language functionality.  TS is just a subset of JS with types.

Comment: If the array is sorted you can write a recursive function that Array.pop() if the condition you want is met.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450992/takewhile-implementation-in-javascript-looking-for-better-ideas more or less.  Are you just looking to implement `takeWhile()` in JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) your array by comparing the accumulated length of all `content`s to the threshold. I haven't written a single line of Dart in my life but I think this mimics the behavior of `takeWhile()`.

```js
const items = [
  { role: "1", content: "theseAre20Characters" }, // <- above threshhold
  { role: "2", content: "theseAre20Characters" }, // <- above threshhold
  { role: "3", content: "theseAre20Characters" }, // 100
  { role: "4", content: "theseAre20Characters" }, // 80
  { role: "5", content: "theseAre20Characters" }, // 60
  { role: "6", content: "theseAre20Characters" }, // 40
  { role: "7", content: "theseAre20Characters" }, // 20
];

let sum = 0;
const threshhold = 100;

const filtered = items
  .reverse()
  .filter((chatEntry) => {
    sum += chatEntry.content.length;
    return sum <= threshhold;
  })
  .reverse();

console.log(filtered);
```

---

Another approach with [`reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight):

```js
const items = [
  { role: "1", content: "theseAre20Characters" }, // 20
  { role: "2", content: "theseAre20Characters" }, // 40
  { role: "3", content: "theseAre20Characters" }, // 60
  { role: "4", content: "theseAre20Characters" }, // 80
  { role: "5", content: "theseAre20Characters" }, // 100
  { role: "6", content: "theseAre20Characters" }, // <- above threshhold
  { role: "7", content: "theseAre20Characters" }, // <- above threshhold
];

let sum = 0;
const threshhold = 100;

const filtered = items.reduceRight((acc, curr) => {
  sum += curr.content.length;
  if (sum <= threshhold) acc.unshift(curr);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: is `.filter` going through the elements from front to back or other way round?

Comment: From front to back, I updated my answer and added two `.reverse()` calls. Thanks for pointing out.